# Exercise and Stress Hormones

Tags: exercise, anxiety-disorders

Does exercise have a direct and positive impact on hormones such as glucocorticoids, catecholamines, growth hormone and prolactin? Moreover, if one keeps a regular weekly exercise routine, is it proven to reduce anxiety and irrational "fight or flight responses" in the short and long term?

Comment: Interesting question - but did you try searching in Google Scholar? There might be some revews and studies.